# Assign value to a new column based on value in a second column grouped by a third column?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have data similar to the following (let's call it `df`):

```
participant item    rating
1           I1      5
1           I2      6
1           I3      6
1           I4      6
1           I5      7
1           I6      6
1           I7      6
1           I8      5
2           I1      4
2           I2      4
2           I3      3
2           I4      2
2           I5      3
2           I6      1
2           I7      2
2           I8      4
3           I1      7
3           I2      6
3           I3      7
3           I4      6
3           I5      3
3           I6      3
3           I7      6
3           I8      4
```

One column for participant number, one for item tested (the same for every participant), the last for ratings on the items. I would like to label **each participant's** rating, so that individual ratings greater than the mean of all ratings for one participant on the eight items are labeled "high response", otherwise "low response".

I figured it is possible to create another column that simply show the mean of rating for every participant:

```
allMeans <- aggregate(df$rating, by=list(df$participant), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Then replicate the mean vector to match the length of the row:

```
df$rating.mean <- rep(allMeans$x, each = 8)
```

Lastly assign the labels to a new column based on the comparison between `df$ratings` and `df$allMeans` every row.

But I am just wondering if there's some function that can achieve this by one line of code or by a more "appealing" solution? Also, what if now the standard of labeling has changed, say we need to label "high" "low" and "medium" based on higher than `mean + sd`, lower than `mean - sd` and in between `mean+sd` and `mean-sd`?

Comment: In base R `ave` adds a column to the original data, calculated by `group`, e.g., `df$allMeans = with(df, ave(rating, participant, FUN = mean))`. So you could use `ave` for the mean, ave again for the sd, then make your calculation. Most people these days prefer using the `dplyr` or `data.table` packages for grouped operations, which would let you do this all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could `group_by` `participant` and compare the `rating` with `mean` `rating` of group and assign labels.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(participant) %>%
  mutate(label = case_when(rating > mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE) ~ "high response", 
                            TRUE ~ "low response"))


#   participant item  rating label        
#         <int> <fct>  <int> <chr>        
# 1           1 I1         5 low response 
# 2           1 I2         6 high response
# 3           1 I3         6 high response
# 4           1 I4         6 high response
# 5           1 I5         7 high response
# 6           1 I6         6 high response
# 7           1 I7         6 high response
# 8           1 I8         5 low response 
# 9           2 I1         4 high response
#10           2 I2         4 high response
# … with 14 more rows
```

The benefit of using `case_when` is it is easy to add multiple conditions with multiple output.

---

In base R, we can use `ave`

```
df$label <- with(df, c("low response", "high response")
                     [(rating > ave(rating, participant)) + 1])
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I was able to do it but also found a error when I tried to turn it into a 3-level labeling: `df <- df %>% group_by(participant) %>%
  mutate(label = case_when(rating >= (mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE) + sd(rating, na.rm = TRUE)/2) ~ "high",  rating <= (mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE) - sd(rating, na.rm = TRUE)/2) ~ "low"), TRUE ~ "medium")` It says [Error: Column TRUE ~ "medium"` is of unsupported type quoted call`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @FINNNNN you just have brackets at wrong place. Try `df %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>% 
  mutate(label = case_when(rating >= (mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE) + sd(rating, na.rm = TRUE)/2) ~ "high", 
                           rating <= (mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE) - sd(rating, na.rm = TRUE)/2) ~ "low", 
                           TRUE ~ "medium"))`